# Maven pom relocation

Tags: maven

### Maven POM relocation

Is it possible to relocate a POM (not the jars) to a new `groupId` and `artifactId`? I was able to relocate jars with a relocation POM but unable to relocate a POM we use to do dependency management.

Comment: <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.my.group</groupId>
                <artifactId>myartifacts</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

Comment: I want the above POM to be automatically redirect to a new location. I tried the same technique (using distributionManagement/relocation) for relocating jar but it doesn't seem to work with POMs.

Answer (score 3):

The following is from the [docs:](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-relocation.html)

- Copy all foo-related files from /bar/foo/ in your Maven repository to a temporary location.
- Change the groupId to org.bar in all foo-related pom files in the temporary location.
- Copy all files from the temporary location to /org/bar/foo/ in your Maven 2 repository.
- Create a minimal Maven pom file for every old release of foo in your Maven 2 repository. The pom files only need to include groupId, artifactId, version and the relocation section.

  Note: Before you replace your old pom files in /bar/foo/ with these minimal pom files, make sure you have made backups!

  The minimal pom file might look like this for version 1.0 of foo:

```xml
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>bar</groupId>
  <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <distributionManagement>
    <relocation>
      <groupId>org.bar</groupId>
    </relocation>
  </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

In this case we are relocating because the groupId has changed. We only need to add the element that has changed to the relocation element. For information on which elements are allowed in the relocation element, see the pom reference.

If your project uses MD5 or SHA1 checksums you must now create new checksums for the pom files in /bar/foo/ in your Maven repository. If the pom file needs to be signed, do that as well.

If your project syncs with central, you should now initiate that sync. This might happen automatically depending on your projects sync policy.

Your foo-artifacts are now available to Maven users with both the old and the new groupId. Projects using the old groupId will automatically be redirected to the new groupId and a warning telling the user to update their dependencies will be issued.
Releasing the next version

When the next release of foo is made, you should publish two Maven pom files. First you should publish a pom with the new groupId org.bar.

Because data in the repository is not supposed to change, Maven doesn't download pom files that it has already downloaded. Therefor you will also need to publish a pom file with the old groupId bar for the new version. This should be a minimal relocation pom (as described in step 4 above), but for the new version of foo.

For the release after that, you only need to publish a Maven pom with a groupId of org.bar, since users of the previous version have been informed of the changed groupId.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Not sure If you read my comments to the question clearly. I have no problem relocating a jar type artifact by following the same document you copied above. My specific scenario is I need to relocate a POM type artifact (just a pom) and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: If it really does not work it would be great if you can open an isse in http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MSITE and maybe we need to move it the correct component.