# com.lowagie.itext version 4.2.2 missing jar file in MVNrepository

Tags: itext

We have an old project that uses Jasper Reports 1.3.4 (the last 1.x version produced) http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jasperreports/jasperreports/1.3.4

It depends on com.lowagie.itext version [1.02b,)

It appears that yesterday a version 4.2.2 was pushed with a POM only and missing the jar file which causes builds to fail. [Dependency error in jasper-reports from itext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31314373/dependecy-error-from-itext)

Can that POM be removed and revert to 4.2.1?  Who pushed that and can they correct the push?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Dependecy error from Itext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31314373/dependecy-error-from-itext)

Comment: The actual issue here is the open ended dependency version range. iText is not the only software changing its API considerably between major versions, some software even between minor version (e.g. BouncyCastle). Thus, an open ended dependency version range almost always is implicitly wrong.