# pom.xml error - Missing artifact com.lowagie:itext:jar:4.2.2, how dowload itext 4.2.2 jar file?

Tags: itext, pom.xml

How I can download itext 4.2.2 jar as using in old project and getting error in pom.xml, I dont want to use and change itextpdf 5.x.x version

error - Missing artifact com.lowagie:itext:jar:4.2.2

Answer (score 1):

iText 4.2.2 does not exist, and has never existed as a jar. If you look at Maven Central for 4.2.2 (https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.lowagie/itext/4.2.2/pom), you will see that it only exists as a redirect to 5.5.6. I know, because I am the person who wrote that version of the POM and uploaded it to Maven Central. This blog post describes in full detail *why* it was done: https://itextpdf.com/en/blog/technical-notes/my-maven-build-broken-what-should-i-do

To fix your build, you either need to use `com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7` (last official release of the 2.x.x version by iText Software) or you can use `com.itextpdf:itextpdf:jar:5.5.13.1`, but then you also have to update all your import statements from `com.lowagie.*` to `com.itextpdf.*`, but apart from that your code *should* work just fine.

Related issues:

- [com.lowagie.itext version 4.2.2 missing jar file in MVNrepository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31318089/com-lowagie-itext-version-4-2-2-missing-jar-file-in-mvnrepository)
- [Dependency error in jasper-reports from itext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31314373/dependency-error-in-jasper-reports-from-itext)
- [iText version 4.2.1 redirected in maven central repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31386309/itext-version-4-2-1-redirected-in-maven-central-repository)
- [What is the difference between lowagie and iText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515210/what-is-the-difference-between-lowagie-and-itext)
- [How to migrate com.lowagie itext form 2.1.7 to 4.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37740725/how-to-migrate-com-lowagie-itext-form-2-1-7-to-4-2-0)
- [What is the Difference between ITEXT and ITEXTPDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41820698/what-is-the-difference-between-itext-and-itextpdf)