# Maven Build Failure with jasperreports

Tags: java, maven, jasper-reports, itext

Since yesterday following build failure message is given when I build the project in NetBeans. There is a dependency for `jasperreports`, and from there a dependency for `itext`. Could not figure out the exact cause for this issue.

`Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.lowagie:itext:jar:4.2.2: Could not transfer artifact com.itextpdf:itextpdf:pom:4.2.2 from/to jaspersoft (http://rs.jaspersoft.com/maven2): rs.jaspersoft.com: Unknown host rs.jaspersoft.com`

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>jasperreports</groupId>
      <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The problem is that the people who created 4.2.1 (InProTopia) didn't follow the rules. To prevent that you import software with malware instead of the real iText, automatic updating of the project is now prevented as explained by Amedee in answer to this question: [Dependency error in jasper-reports from itext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31314373/dependency-error-in-jasper-reports-from-itext)

Comment: Your question is a duplicate, but clean out your local maven cache. The itext 4.2.2 metadata has been updated on Maven Central. You will now get  [WARNING] The artifact com.lowagie:itext:jar:4.2.2 has been relocated to com.itextpdf:itextpdf:jar:5.5.6

Comment: Have you tried using a more recent version of `jasperreports`, which does not have the dependency problem?