# Why does maven installs itextsharp's dependency in my project instead com.lowagie.itext?

Tags: java, maven

I have a pom.xml file and have a dependency for itext

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

When I run the `mvn clean install -DskipTests -P <profile_name>` command, I get a compilation error `"package com.lowagie.text does not exist"`.
I checked the Maven dependency folder in Eclipse and found the below dependency in the image instead of "itext-4.1.2.jar" :

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bl5lA.png)

The same maven command when I run it on my colleague's machine, it runs properly without any error.

It would be a great help if someone helps me in resolving this issue.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: As you mention profiles: Maybe the dependencies are different in different profiles?

Comment: Nope, I checked the profiles. All have the same dependency

Comment: Then have a look at `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: I ran the above command and got the following warning message : The artifact com.lowagie:itext:jar:4.2.1 has been relocated to com.itextpdf:itextpdf:jar:5.5.6.


The itext-4.2.1 redirects to itextsharp.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31386309/itext-version-4-2-1-redirected-in-maven-central-repository

Comment: I commented out the reallocation part in the pom.xml of the itext-4.2.1 in the m2 repo and it solved my problem.

Thank you @JFabianMeier for your help :)