# Why does jasperreports-maven-plugin needs itext:itext:jar:4.2.0?

Tags: maven, jasper-reports, itext, maven-plugin, dependency-management

Since today we can't build our jasper file any more.  We use the jasperreports-maven-plugin for this.

In maven 2.2.1, this was configured like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-beta-2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>compile-reports</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/reports</sourceDirectory>
          <outputDirectory>>${project.build.directory}/classes/reports</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
      <sourceDirectory>C:\Windows\TEMP/src/main/resources/reports</sourceDirectory>
      <outputDirectory>C:\Windows\TEMP\target/classes/reports</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

But, as said, since today, we got this build error:

```
...
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/itext/itext/4.2.0/itext-4.2.0.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.

Missing:
----------
1) itext:itext:jar:4.2.0

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command:
  mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=itext -DartifactId=itext -Dversion=4.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
  mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=itext -DartifactId=itext -Dversion=4.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency:
    1) org.codehaus.mojo:jasperreports-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:1.0-beta-2
    2) jasperreports:jasperreports:jar:1.2.0
    3) itext:itext:jar:4.2.0
```

I think another question ([Dependency error in jasper-reports from itext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31314373/dependency-error-in-jasper-reports-from-itext/)) is related to his.  And I tried the solution of Meher to use maven 3.2.3.  This seems to be a solution, but we can't upgrade (now) to this maven version.  So I need another solution to resolve this issue.  Any ideas?  I already tried to exclude dependencies and use fixed versions, but I haven't managed to succeed my build.  What I mean is this:

```
<!-- Compile jasper reports -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-beta-2</version>
    <configuration>
        <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/reports</sourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/reports</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile-reports</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta-2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>                              
                </exclusion>                            
            </exclusions>
        </dependency> 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.1</version> 
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
                    <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Why is the plugin still searching for itext:itext:jar:4.2.0?  Any ideas or suggestions to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: I think it should be enough to replace the central repository url. It may just be using https - so the current url is still: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ - so in you settings.xml add a repository with id "central" and let it point to that url. itext is still there.

Comment: So, you mean I can find itext 4.2.0  in this repository?  I already tried this, and it isn't there.  That's why I am trying to use a fixed version of itext.

Comment: hm. I think the groupId is not correct. itext:itext is for ealrier versions. the 4.2.x versions have com.lowagie:itext (groupId:artifactId). I would use "mvn help:dependency-tree" to figure out where that dependency comes from. Maybe the transitive dependency is ok but it is overwritten by something in your own pom.xml

Comment: The depency tree is jasperreports-maven-plugin / jasperreports / itext.  So, the cause is somewhere in the plugin depencies

Comment: According to the jasperreports `6.1.0` pom.xml on Maven Central, they depend on `com.lowagie:itext` `2.1.7.js`. That's a version of iText especially for jasperreports. Which version of jasperreports are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue by using ant to build my jasper report.  So I skipped the plugin.

My ant task looks like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-antrun-plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>compile-jasper-reports</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>         
                <target>
                        <echo message="Start compile of jasper reports"/>                               
                            <mkdir dir="${project.build.directory}/classes/reports"/>

                    <taskdef name="jrc" classname="net.sf.jasperreports.ant.JRAntCompileTask" classpathref="maven.compile.classpath" />
                    <jrc srcdir="${basedir}/src/main/resources/reports"
                         destdir="${project.build.directory}/classes/reports"
                         tempdir="${project.build.directory}/classes/reports"
                         keepjava="true"
                         xmlvalidation="true">
                           <classpath refid="maven.compile.classpath"/>
                           <include name="**/*.jrxml"/>
                    </jrc>                              
                    </target>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This works, because I don't see you setting a version for jasperreports, so you are using the latest version, which has a dependency on itext `2.1.7.js`, see answer above. (solution 4)

Answer (score 3):

Background:

iText Group NV is owner of the groupId `com.lowagie` and `com.itextpdf` on Maven Central. iText Group NV released `com.lowagie:itext` version **2.1.7** in July 2009. The next release by iText Group NV was `com.itextpdf:itextpdf` version **5.0.0**, in December 2009. The current version (as of December 2015) is **5.5.8**.

*iText Group NV never released a version **4.x.x**.*

Somewhere in 2011, a company called InProTopia "hijacked" `com.lowagie` and released a fork of iText with version number **4.2.0**. According to the [Guidelines of Maven Central][1], they should have published this as `com.inprotopia:itext`, but they didn't. Later they published a **4.2.1** with their own patches. Recently iText Group NV took ownership of `com.lowagie` and published a version **4.2.2** with redirection to `com.itextpdf:itextpdf` version **5.5.6** (the current version at that time).

Possible solutions:

1. If you need `com.lowagie` iText, you need to set a fixed version in your `pom.xml`. The last official release is **2.1.7**.
2. If you need iText **4.x.x**, contact InProTopia. Good luck with that, because their website is down, and as far as I could find out, that company no longer exists.
3. If you don’t mind which version of iText you use, use the current version of iText published by iText Group NV, `com.itextpdf:itextpdf` **5.5.8** (as of December 2015).
4. Use the latest version of `jasperreports`. It has an explicit dependency on iText `2.1.7.js`, which a custom iText version for Jasper Reports.

More info at the iText blog. 
http://itextpdf.com/maven-update-problem-with-itext-4.2.2

[1] https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html

Comment: I indeed want to use itext 2.1.7, but I have difficulties in using this version (instead of 4.2.0).  In our project we use jasperreports 5.5.1 and itext 2.1.7, but the jasperreports-maven-plugin still wants to use 4.2.0 for some reason.

Comment: In that case I suggest you contact Jasper Reports for support.

Answer (score 0):

Try add this repository:

```
<repository>
        <url>https://repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        <id>liferay</id>
        <name>Liferay</name>
    </repository>
```

Good luck!