# Error:Failed to resolve: com.itextpdf:itextpdf:4.2.2

Tags: android, itext, pdf-generation

I am trying to create pdf files in android using itext library. But whenever i run the project, I am getting the following error.

```
Error:Failed to resolve: com.itextpdf:itextpdf:4.2.2
```

I have entered the following dependencies in my gradle.

```
compile 'com.lowagie:itext:4.2.2'
compile 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.9'
```

Can someone please help in this. I have searched a lot on internet but have found nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dependency error in jasper-reports from itext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31314373/dependency-error-in-jasper-reports-from-itext)

Comment: Remove the 4.2.2 dependency.

Comment: After removing com.lowagie:itext:4.2.2 dependancy, I am not able to use PdfWriter , Font and other classes of itext library. To make those things work, I had to import com.lowagie.itext, but after removing that import, I am unable to use above mentioned classes of itext library.

Comment: You need to import `com.itextpdf`, not import `com.lowagie`. All mentioned classes are in `com.itextpdf`. See for yourself in the API docs: http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/5.5.9/ Post your code if it still does not work.

Comment: I have trued importing com.itextpdf class but i think it has been updated and now it does not contain the mentioned classes.

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: When I add this dependency `compile 'com.itextpdf:itextpdf-5.5.6'`,I am getting the following error `Error:Failed to resolve: com.itextpdf:itextpdf-5.5.6`

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot something. Show us your code PLEASE.

Comment: Furthermore, please explain why you think something like `compile 'com.lowagie:itext:4.2.2'` should work. While one can argue that there once had been a 4.2.0 version (it was internal, but it existed in publicly accessible version control nonetheless), there never was a version 4.2.1 or 4.2.2 by the iText people. So who told you to use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to create an Android application, you need to use iTextG, so this is correct:

```
compile 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.9'
```

However, you are also importing a rogue version of iText that doesn't work on Android:

```
compile 'com.lowagie:itext:4.2.2'
```

You need to remove that dependency.

Please compare the package name with my name: [Lowagie](http://lowagie.com). I am the original developer of iText, and because of the fact that so many people contacted (or even harassed me) personally with questions about iText, I changed the package names from `com.lowagie` to `com.itextpdf` in 2009. That's almost 8 years ago.

If you see my name in your code, then [you are doing something wrong](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/versions-older-than-5). Replace all `import com.lowagie` instances with `import com.itextpdf` because I removed my name from the packaged names 8 years ago.

Comment: Thankx, this solved my problem. And thanks for creating such a library for android.