# Dependency can't be found if gradle version is increased

Tags: java, gradle

We currently use gradle 5.6.4 version. After I upgrade the gradle version, above 6, I tried with 6.3 and 6.7.1, the following error occurs:

```
What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.

   > Could not find com.lowagie:itext:2.1.7.js8.

     Required by:

         project : > net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:6.16.0
```

The dependency exists in ".gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1". I also tried with --refresh-dependencies flag, but nothing works. Any ideas?

Comment: You should include your build.gradle as well :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. Some solutions which worked for me:

1. Adding new repositories

```
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven{url "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/maven2/"}
        maven{url "http://jaspersoft.artifactoryonline.com/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/"
    }

    dependencies {
        ...
        implementation 'net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:6.16.0'
        ...
    }
```

2. Excluding a deprecated artifact (com.lowagie)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>6.16.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

PS. Similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31314373/dependency-error-in-jasper-reports-from-itext) with itext library

Comment: Adding the jaspersoft repos seems to solve the problem but what I don't understand is, why is this happening with gradle version >= 6 and not with 5.6.4. We use nexus from our company. What's different between gradle versions regarding dependencies?

Comment: I'm not sure, but perhaps this is because in Gradle 6.3 we got different behavior in terms of security and the way how dependencies from external repos are fetched.

Comment: Adding only third-party repo works (see https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports/issues/148). No need for exclusion or adding more repos.

Answer (score 0):

I got the following build error:

> `Could not find com.lowagie:itext:2.1.7.js6`

So I added http://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/ as repository and now it works.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/" }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:6.8.0'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. I externally added the dependency for itext 2.1.7, which required for the complier.

implementation 'com.lowagie:itext:2.1.7'

implementation 'net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:6.17.0'